# Create a submit button in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm doing fine with this code but would like to have a submit button that will help me submit a form in addition to it. From this, I also want to get the value of input text through request.vars in controller.

```
this.typeInput = function(callbackFn) {
    var inputWrap = document.createElement("div")
    inputWrap.className = "input-wrap"
    var inputText = document.createElement("textarea")
    inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", "Ask me anything...")
    inputWrap.appendChild(inputText)
    inputText.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
          // register user input
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault()
            typeof bubbleQueue !== false ? clearTimeout(bubbleQueue) : false // allow user to interrupt the bot
```

When I try to add a function as `inputText.setAttribute('type','submit')` i get a blank screen.
Am I missing something

Comment: You got an error as you tried to set type attribute on textarea, not button. Create a button element and then set an 'submit' attribute on it.

Comment: It is good practice to single `javascript` line of code with a semi-colon `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var inputText = document.createElement("textarea")` is creating a textarea, you need to create a button t have the type='submit"

`var btn = document.createElement("button")
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button")`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is creating textarea not button so Replace,

```
var inputText = document.createElement("textarea");
```

with

```
var button= document.createElement("button");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
this.typeInput = function (callbackFn) {
    var inputWrap = document.createElement("div");
    inputWrap.className = "input-wrap";

    var inputText = document.createElement("textarea");
    inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", "Ask me anything...");
    inputWrap.appendChild(inputText);
    inputText.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        // register user input
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            typeof bubbleQueue !== false ? clearTimeout(bubbleQueue) : false;
        }
    }
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    inputWrap.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        typeof bubbleQueue !== false ? clearTimeout(bubbleQueue) : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting a blank page

Comment: @loved_by_Jesus If you could provide more code(HTML, JavaScript etc.) then it would help clarify your problem

Comment: Sorry I had a typo somewhere

Comment: The button is working well. How ever i have just noted that when I refresh the page, next comes a blank screen with the input area and button still present. I'll post the whole code shortly

Comment: cant post the whole code but you can find it here :https://github.com/dmitrizzle/chat-bubble/blob/master/examples/3-keyboard-input.html

Comment: @loved_by_Jesus The code you have shown on github does not have `typeInput()` function definition and is not used anywhere.

Comment: In the component folder, there is a file: Bubble.js